# rails_admin table of has_many in the show?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I would like to show a related has_many set of objects in the show view of the parent object as a table.

Currently the has_many items are just being shown as a list separated by commas.

How can I show the has_many items as a table and specify the columns to include?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

For example **Article** has_many **Autors**.

Then you should just add in **Article** class:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :autors, allow_destroy: true
attr_accessible :autors_attributes
```

More info https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: I don't understand why this is an accepted answer. This doesn't answer the OP problem.